# Is Eager Loading case-sensitive?

Tags: php, laravel

Taking in consideration the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading lets have the following example:

```
$clients = Clients::with('Addresses')->get();
```

We can now loop `addresses` like:

```
foreach ($clients->Addresses ..) 

foreach ($clients->addresses ..)
```

If we use the first approach (with case-sensitive) does that mean that the Eager Loading results will be ignored and another query will be done or not?

As you know, If we do something like:

```
$clients = Clients::get();
```

We are still able to loop through the addresses but another query will be taking place.

```
foreach ($clients->Addresses ..)
```

Comment: Did you try it? Pretty sure you could answer this yourself quite quickly with a `php artisan tinker` session... From my test (`Thing::with('Something')->first()` and `Thing::with('something')->first()`) returns the same results, including eager loaded relationship.

Comment: @TimLewis I don't know how to test it xD

Comment: Haha no worries; there are other ways to test it, but regardless :) If you do a `dd()` on any Model instance, you should see the `relationships` property. If that has `addresses` in it, then you have eagerloaded a relationship, and `$model->addresses` will not run an extra query.

Comment: @TimLewis seems fair. I was printing the output like oldschool and the values returned are identical, but I wasn't sure that using `->Addresses` would not cause an extra query to be run even after being loaded in Eager, since I can use `->Addresses` without Eager.

Comment: Huh, interesting; I might be wrong actually. `Thing::with('something')->first()->something;` runs 2 queries (load, eager loadl), while `Thing::with('something')->Something;` runs 3 (load, eager load, additional). Same with case on `something` reversed: `Thing::with('Something')->first()->something;` and `Thing::with('Something')->first()->Something;` (2 vs 3 queries). So TL;DR, it seems to be case-insensitive as long as the case used while loading is also used later.

Comment: @TimLewis I'm trying to figure this out because I always use Capital Letter in all my loops / accessing the property..and I'm might be doing extra queries without knowing.

Comment: Oh boy, you definitely are lol. See this example: `$thing = Thing::with(['other_things' => function($q){ $q->limit(1); }])->first()`. I'm loading a single Thing with a single other associated thing, but then: `dd($thing->other_things->count(), $thing->Other_Things-count());` returns 1 and 202 (in my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some quick tests, it seems that while Eager Loaded is in fact case-insensitive, it is only so when using the same case while loading and while accessing. For your example:

```
$clients = Client::with(['addresses' => function ($q) {
  $q->limit(2);
}])->get();

// Good
foreach ($clients as $client){
  foreach ($client->addresses as $address) {
    // Should loop twice and output 2 Addresses
  }
}

// Bad
foreach ($clients as $client){
  foreach ($client->Addresses as $address) {
    // Will loop X times for each associated `address`
  }
}
```

The use of `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `DB::getQueryLog()` can assist with debugging. If you're eager loading, you should see a row:

```
"query" => "select * from `addresses` where `addresses`.`client_id` in (...) limit 1
```

If an additional query is being run while iterating, you'll see a query for each Client:

```
"query" => "select * from `addresses` where `addresses`.`client_id` = ? and `addresses`.`client_id` is not null",
```

There are a multitude of other methods to test this, but the long and short of it is that accessing `$client->addresses` and `$client->Addresses` does in fact produce different outcomes, even if they seem similar. Use the same case for loading that you use while accessing and you'll be good. Note that since relationships are functions, using the correct case for PHP functions (`studlyCaps` aka `pascalCase`) should be your go-to approach.

Comment: I was just testing with the `queryLog`, I'll give you an answer in a minute.

Comment: You are right! Fortunately I don't have to go fix in all my projects/code since I always use capital letter. I tested with a even more simple example https://pastebin.com/tu1UUSVH and in fact it produces more queries!

Comment: Awesome, and great approach to debugging! While I would argue against using `Client` vs `client` (case preference for methods), it doesn't matter too much, **as long as you're consistent**. Cheers!

Comment: I only use the first capital letter in Eager Loadings, that way I know that in my view when I'm accessing a property if it is Capitalized it means it's from another table / relation. Thanks!